# count records from two date criteria

Tags: vba, excel

hope I can get any help on this.. I have tried counting records which are meeting two dates criteria (date criteria are dynamic so will keep changing, I have put it on next sheet from the data here is code I am trying to run which is bringing me blank result here is my code which I have gathered so far using macro:

```
Worksheets("Data").Select
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BN$235").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=COUNTIFS(DOB," >= "&R[1]C,DOB,""<=""&R[1]C[1])"

ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("error"))
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
NewSheet.Name = "DOBrange"
NewSheet.Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Worksheets("Data").Select
Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: when I am doing same countifs formula in excel using same criteria and data i am getting accurate counting of dates matching those two criteria dates, while running VB code it comes up as blank result - it must be using something else as criteria since not coming as error

Comment: Date criteria is in sheet name "error" in a20 & b20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to filter rows by selecting values between two dates, however your criteria is saying you want to select values equal to something (which seems to be attempting to say all values equal to the count of values that have dates between two other dates - so if five dates were within the range, you are attempting to say filter to show all values that are `5`).

The correct way to select values between two dates would be by saying:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BN$235").AutoFilter _
                   Field:=4, _
                   Criteria1:=">=" & Worksheets("Error").Range("A20").Value2, _
                   Operator:=xlAnd, _
                   Criteria2:="<=" & Worksheets("Error").Range("B20").Value2
```

(assuming the two dates are in cells A20 and B20 of worksheet "error")

Comment: Have you tested it ? sometimes the `"Dates"` are a little tricky. I've found out that usualy you need you to `Cdbl("Dates")` to get it working preoperly.

Comment: @ShaiRado - didn't test that specific code, but did test with `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$28").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=" & Cells(35, 10).Value2, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Cells(36, 10).Value2`.  My column D was set with dates starting with Today and adding 1, and my J35 and J36 were set to 31/03/2017 and 5/04/2017.

Comment: Let's hope the PO has his cells date's formatted as you are :) I found that most questions invlove some "crazy" dates and numeric formatting, you are going to sweat to get the **V** here ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado It should work irrespective of date "formatting" - as long as the cells contain dates.  (I've given up ever expecting to get ticks of approval - most answers I give are on questions posted by people with a rep of 1, so they don't understand that they should tick answers when they work :D  Just noticed - this OP has rep 13 - so there might be a chance!)

Comment: that +1 is my contribution for your correct code. When I mean formatting, I am talking about "Dates" like " 10 APRIL 2017" entered in a cell as `Text`

Comment: @ShaiRado - The OP commented that "when I am doing same countifs formula in excel using same criteria and data i am getting accurate counting of dates matching those two criteria dates" so it **sounds** like the dates are valid dates.  (P.S.  Thanks for the +1 - every little bit is appreciated. :) )

Comment: @YowE3K i highly appreciate your help, thanks a lot for the detail explaination, re date format - i have my date column formatted as Date                                     DOBCoountBlank()
    Worksheets("data").Select
    Worksheets("data").Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 3).Select
    Selection.Name = "DOB"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Comment: @YowE3K as what i have copied from macro is not working (basically its not picking the correct reference to filter, ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BN$235").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=COUNTIFS(DOB," >= "&R[1]C,DOB,""<=""&R[1]C[1])"  , would you please see what the issue in syntax? this is just for applying filter and sorting data which match the criteria, what i am getting here is blank, so it dose filter but not as per the criteria given, in first place it should filter the data and rest of the code will copy that data into new sheet.. your expert comment please , n i did vote on the answer:)

Comment: Sorry, that was a dumb question, in criteria i wrote to 'count the dates' which matches criteria, and i was expecting it to perform 'filtering'

Answer (score 0):

You have problem at the criteria1 statement

```
Criteria1:="=COUNTIFS(DOB," >= "&R[1]C,DOB,""<=""&R[1]C[1])"
```

You can see that text color of >= is black while other is brown. this mean vba will compare between "=COUNTIFS(DOB," and "&R[1]C,DOB,""<=""&R[1]C[1])" then criteria1 will be True or False. so you will not get the result vary by your condition

The code below may fix this problem

```
Criteria1:="=COUNTIFS(DOB, "">=""" & R[1]C & ",DOB,""<=""" & R[1]C[1] & ")"
```

Comment: i tried running this code but its coming up as syntx error, there is a problem in referencing as i could see criteria are not referring to where i intended

Comment: Could you send me the file?

Comment: Plz share your email

Comment: i have got the solution to this, thank you for your help, much appreciated